# Inserting a Node in a singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm currently writing an "insert" function for a linked list. The code works but I would like to know if there is any way I can improve this code and at the same time covering all the "special" cases.`

```
private class Node{
    Node next;
    int data;

    public Node(int data, Node next){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node(){
        this.next = null;
        this.data = 0;
    }}`




public void insert(int data) {
    if(first == null || first.item != data){
        first = new Node(data, first);
    }
    else{
        Node x = first;
        while(x.next != null && x.next.item != data){
            x.next = new Node(data, x.next);
        }
        x = x.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: So it's a linkedlist that can only contains int, right ? As you didn't put much code, can you add the Node class before we start reviewing ?

Comment: Yes, it contains integers. Just added the Node class.

Comment: It is still missing too much code.  `insert` is part of some other class which contains for example `first`.

Comment: This question looks incomplete. For example the class that contains  `insert` is missing. Also, it's unclear what is `first`, and where the `.item` property comes from that is referenced in the `insert` method. Finally, what "special cases" are you talking about? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public Node(){
>       this.next = null;
>       this.data = 0;
> }
> ```

As used, your no-arg constructor can be reduced to `Node() {}` The default instance values for objects and integers is null and 0 respectively; this is redundant.

In your `insert` method you refer to `item` yet it has no reference anywhere, I'm guessing that's supposed to be `data` but that's conjecture. The same goes for wherever `first` comes from. I'm guessing the actual linkedList class keeps reference to it, but again without the context this is purely speculation.

I would suggest you ponder why linkedlists are used. When you think of the answer you might realize you want to keep a reference to `tail` and `prev` as well.